# Android Custom View Spacing

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to make a custom view that will have a dynamic number of pages (1-3) that each contain a dynamic number of child views (3-6). The pages aren't actually defined, they are just virtual groups of the child views. One page fits across the screen width.

My problem is that I can't space the children equally without using `child.setMinimumWidth(screenWidth / mChildrenPerPage)`, but this makes them too high. How can I keep them at the original height AND space them out equally. Here is my code

```
    mIconWidth = screenWidth  / mChildrenPerPage;

    for (int i = 0; i < mPages; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mChildrenPerPage; j++) {
            View icon = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, this, false);

            ((ImageView)icon).setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.some_icon));
            icon.setMinimumWidth(mIconWidth);
            addView(icon);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set up an xml layout and set the layout_weight manually.